# Authenticating with user name different from UPN or samAccountName

Tags: jboss, active-directory, wildfly, kerberos

I am using org.jboss.security.negotiation.AdvancedLdapLoginModule in wildfly to get a list of groups user belongs to. To get the list I have this in configuration:

```
<module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
```

It passes login name instead of {0} to match with UPN

The name in UPN is in FirstName.LastName@OUR.DOMAIN.COM. Login name that I get is FirstLetterOfFirstNameLastName@OUR.DOMAIN.COM (this is how our AD is setup).

There is samAccountName field in AD and it's FirstLetterOfFirstNameLastName, so it doesn't have the domain name added at the end.

My question is - how can I match the username? Is there a way to do some kind of transformation in the config so I can remove the domain name and only use username?

My standalone config (relevant parts)

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.security.krb5.conf" value="/etc/krb5.conf"/>
    <property name="java.security.krb5.debug" value="true"/>
    <property name="java.security.disable.secdomain.option" value="true"/>
</system-properties>

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="keyTab" value="/pathtokeytab/keytab_name.keytab"/>
                        <module-option name="principal" value="host/principal_name@OUR.DOMAIN.COM"/>
                        <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="require" value="valid-user"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="requisite">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.AdvancedLdapLoginModule" flag="requisite">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://globalcatalog.ad.mlp.com:3268/"/>
                        <module-option name="bindDN" value="ldap_user"/>
                        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="ldap_password"/>
                        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=AD,DC=OURDOMAIN,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="DC=AD,DC=OURDOMAIN,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                        <module-option name="recurseRoles" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        <module-option name="allowEmptyPassword" value="false"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Please clarify about {0} in your statement *"It passes login name instead of {0} to match with UPN"*. Also, can you share the screenshot of any sample test-user's UPN and sAMAccountName from ADUC / dsa.msc (where both are visible)?

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/negotiation_user_guide/appendix-advancedldap . So, for me login name is rgoyenko@OUR.DOMAIN.COM (and that's what will be in {0}), UPN would be roman.goyenko@OUR.DOMAIN.COM and samAccountName would be rgoyenko .

Comment: Can you please add the configuration from your standalone.xml

Comment: @wirnse - added